# ng-model is not updating with $setViewValue (adopting jquery-ui autocomplete)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui

Here is full example on jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/m5Lgu/

Here is code of the dircetive:

```
app.directive('autoComplete', function() {
    return {
        scope: { 'uiSrc': '@' },
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            el.autocomplete({
                source: opts,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    el.val(ui.item.label);
                    scope.$apply(function() {  ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(el.val())  });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And usage of directive:

```
<input type="text" auto-complete ng-model="view.fld" autocomplete="off" size="28">
```

It is expected that `fld` field will be set to autcomplete suggestion value when clicked on it, but in reality this not happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **$parent.** before **view.fld** because your directive have own isolated scope.

```
<input type="text" data-auto-complete="" data-ng-model="$parent.view.fld" autocomplete="off" size="28" />
```

Comment: I noticed that upgrading to Angular 1.2 is also fixes this issue, and @Nix offered another 2 working solutions. but this one is simplest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert at this but I have two suggestions.  You are dealing with an `isolated scope` issue.  I wish I could explain why, but I will defer that to a greater mind.

1. remove `scope: {}` from your directive.  (Probably not the right call).
2. Use ngModel directly and set it.  [Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/uvasL/)  (your jquery-ui is not working bc of version mismatch)

---

```
link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
    scope: {
      'uiSrc': '@',
      'ngModel': '='
    },
    el.autocomplete({
      ...
      select: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                el.val(ui.item.label);
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    //debugger
                    scope.ngModel = el.val();
                    //ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(el.val()) 
                });
  }
```